# DAX - Replacing EXCEPT and INTERSECT with NATURALLEFTOUTERJOIN in a Measure

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas-tabular

All,

The Left join in T-SQL (SQLServer) displays all the matching rows in TableA (left table) & TableB (right table) along with the rows from TableA that do not match. And for those columns in TableB it displays a NULL value which helps in further processing of the unmatched data.

***For the DAX Query below:***

```
EVALUATE
VAR A =
UNION (
ROW ( "Name", "Audio", "Value", 1 ),
ROW ( "Name", "Audio", "Value", 2 ),
ROW ( "Name", "Audio", "Value", 2 ),
ROW ( "Name", "Computers", "Value", 3 ),
ROW ( "Name", "Games", "Value", 4 ),
ROW ( "Name", "Music", "Value", 5 )
)
VAR B =
UNION (
ROW ( "Name", "Audio", "Value", 2 ),
ROW ( "Name", "Computers", "Value", 3 ),
ROW ( "Name", "Computers", "Value", 8 ),
ROW ( "Name", "Games", "Value", 9 ),
ROW ( "Name", "TV", "Value", 10 )
)
RETURN
-- intersect ( A, B )
 NATURALLEFTOUTERJOIN ( A, B )
-- EXCEPT ( A, B )
```

***From the below result, one cant make out which of the rows are matching and which of the rows are not matching.***

```
[Name]  [Value]
Audio   1
Audio   2
Audio   2
Computers   3
Games   4
Music   5
```

***Where as, something like the below would help :***

```
[Name]  [Value TableA]  [Value TableB]  
Audio   1               NULL
Audio   2               2
Audio   2               2
Computers   3           3
Games   4               NULL
Music   5               NULL
```

I need to optimize a DAX measure which uses **EXCEPT** on one occasion and **INTERSECT** on another occasion and I was hoping to get the data once using **NATURALLEFTOUTERJOIN** and use it later for further processing.

Thanks,
grajee

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Alexis, using DAX can I get the output as mentioned in the last result set. If I can get the result this way, I can further extract the data using filters or whatever to satisfy my EXCEPT and INTERSECT needs. If this is not possible then I have to run the same query twice - once with EXCEPT and another time with INTERSECT